# Replace only substrings that have specified string before and specified string after

Tags: c#, regex, replace, .net-core

I want replace substrings in string that have specified substring before and specified substring after.

I have dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dicrionary<string, string>
{
   {"From","DateFrom"}
}
```

which represents transformation of names in source string.

Then I have:

```
var source = "(From|DistanceFrom|Name)";
foreach (var key in map.Keys)
{
   var findWholeVarsNamesPattern = $"^({key})$|(\\({key}\\|)|(\\|{key}\\))|(\\|{key}\\|)";
   source = Regex.Replace(source, map[key], findWholeVarsNamesPattern);
}
```

How can I modify `findWholeVarsNamesPattern` to replace only `"From"` substring in source instead of `"(From|"` but not modify `"DistanceFrom"`?

So to summarize I expect to replace word `"From"` that have:

- nothing after and before or
- have "(" before and "|" after or
- have "|" before and "|" after or
- have "|" before and ")" after.

Comment: Maybe enclose the key within word boundaries (i.e., `\\b{key}\\b`)?

Comment: Note that word boundaries might only work if the keys have no spaces or other non-word chars inside. Another way out may be sorting the keys by length in the descending order.

Comment: You may fix your current approach using `$@"^{key}$|(?<=\(){key}(?=\|)|(?<=\|){key}(?=[)|])"` and use `source = Regex.Replace(source, findWholeVarsNamesPattern, map[key]);`

Comment: @H.Wojtowicz  Your source can contain non-word chars, like `"(From-One|DistanceFrom|Name)";`? In this case, it should be replaced or not? How about whitespaces?

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex.Replace order is wrong, it should be `string input, string pattern, string replacement`. Try this pattern:

```
var findWholeVarsNamesPattern = $@"\b{key}\b";   
source = Regex.Replace(source, findWholeVarsNamesPattern, map[key]);
```

Comment: Note that if `key` contains a non-word char this approach might not work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, OP must clarify if that is allowed or not, I'll ask

Comment: `\\b{key}\\b` is good enough to fulfill requirements. Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually the  `key` can contain non-word char, but the string inside `source` cannot. For example, a key like `From-` would correctly replace a source like `(From-|...)` but the same source with the key `From` would fail